# Joe 4.6: How do I override color definitions?

Tags: joe

After upgrading from Debian 9 (Joe 4.4) to Debian 10 (Joe 4.6), the following lines in my joerc started creating errors:

```
=Preproc    yellow
=Tag    cyan bold
```

I used this to override the default colour scheme, which has C pre-processor lines in dark blue, which is very difficult to read when using a terminal with black background.

I am unable to find documentation on how to do this in 4.6, the entire section on colours has just disappeared from the default /etc/joerc.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is the answer that is no longer supported: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/286925/151014

Comment: @RomanRiabenko The linked answer is the message mentioned in the question, which no longer works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Color changes in JOE are now done in the `/usr/share/joe/colors` directory. Edit the `default.jcf` file there or in `~/.joe/colors/default.jcf`

See [the JOE manual](https://joe-editor.sourceforge.io/4.6/man.html#color-scheme-files) for details.

Comment: Copying the /usr/share/joe/colors/default.jcf to ~/.joe/colors/default.jcf and changing the two colours I had previously overridden does indeed work, thanks!